# How to have jquery upload accept all file types but php & js

Tags: jquery-file-upload

I have this line on [Jquery file upload:](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/)

```
'accept_file_types' => '/.+$/i',
```

how to I modify that so it accepts all file types except PHP and Javascript files?

Answer (score 5):

original

```
'accept_file_types' => '/.+$/i',
```

change with

```
'accept_file_types' => '/\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i'
```

or add new extension

```
'accept_file_types' => '/\.(gif|jpe?g|png|zip|pdf)$/i'
```