# PHP Allow Multiple Filetypes

Tags: php, upload

I'm trying to edit this bit of code within my template. I managed to set it to only accept .PNG files but would like to insert a list of files I'd like to accept such as .png,.jpg,.doc etc.

```
'accept_file_types'       => COUNT($acceptedFileTypes) ? ('/(\.|\/)(' . str_replace(".", "", implode("|", $acceptedFileTypes)) . ')$/i') : '/.png+$/i',
```

Tried a lot of different things but almost everything I've tried breaks the upload system. Would like some help adding more filetypes to this line. Thanks

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14741239/how-to-have-jquery-upload-accept-all-file-types-but-php-js